# Unable to figure out the groupby question

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am not able to understand what is asked in the question. Can somebody please explain it to me?

[image]

The given dataset is this, with 15 countries, 5 continent and countries population, renewable (continuous values) etc.

[image]

Comment: read about group-by Online.... as simple as that or show us what you did... Welcome Aboard..   This link might help you... https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/28546/35644

Comment: Yeah Aditya, I know how to use group-by function in pandas. My doubt is that I did not get what question is really asking, sorry about the misleading title, I could not think of a better one. Also I am not expecting a solution to the question but just an understanding of the meaning of a question.

Comment: I believe that this question is surely having some dependencies on the previous ones..., Because it seems that you must already have top 15 with you, a dict to map continent and county and then add a new column named bins which can be achieved by using pd.cut()... And then groupby

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for posting an answer (rather than commenting), I just don't have enough reputation to leave comments yet.

I recognize this question from Coursera's Applied Data Science Specialization.

You should be asking for clarification on the course's discussion forums (where those running the course will decide how much information it's appropriate to give you), not here.

Comment: Yeah this question is from the course. As I wrote above in the comment that I am not expecting a solution to the question but just an idea what is being asked in the question because I could not comprehend. Yeah I will post  it in discussion forum of the course :)